# How do I trouble shoot a status code: 500 error for gtrendsR?

Tags: r, error-handling, gtrendsr

I am trying to use gtrendsR to pull daily data for about 30 timeframes. For the past week, it has been returning data with no errors but it started returning "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Status code was not 200. Returned status code:500" for a few time periods yesterday and now I get this error for every request I make.

I have looked through other posts dealing with different error codes but I haven't found a solution yet and I am not sure how to approach debugging because I have so little information about the problem. How should I go about diagnosing and addressing this error?

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates a problem completely within the server, for any number of reasons. It seems unlikely that you have visibility to those reasons. It might be that how you are forming your request is wrong ... or you could be correct and something is wrong with the server side of things. If the basic example code (`gtrends(c("nhl", "nba"), geo = c("CA", "US"))`) no longer works, it is likely a bug or server outage, otherwise please [edit] your question to include your code and the actual errors/warnings.